# Create Non duplicate view in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

1. Developers

   - Developer_Id
   - Full Name
   - Cellphone number
   - Email address
   - Team
   - Role
   - Assigned To
2. JobList

   - Job_Id
   - Assignment Name
   - Assignment Description
   - Created By
   - Date Created
   - Due Date
   - Status

I want to view the JobList table but it should include:

- Developers.Full Name
- Developers.Team
- Developers.Role
- Developers.Assigned To

I created a view but it return duplicate values like this:

[image]

is there any way I can view the JobList table in a single row but include the muliple rows from the Developers table, something like this

[image]

Here is the code I use

Create Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Developers] (
[Developer_Id]     INT          NOT NULL,
[Full Name]        VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Cellphone number] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Email address]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Team]             VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Role]             VARCHAR (50) NULL, 
[Assigned To] INT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_Developers] PRIMARY KEY ([Developer_Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JobList] (
[Job_Id]                 INT           NOT NULL,
[Assignment Name]        VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Assignment Description] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Created By]             VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Date Created]           DATE          NULL,
[Due Date]               DATE          NULL, 
[Status] VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_JobList] PRIMARY KEY ([Job_Id])
);
```

Create view

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].AssignedJobs
AS SELECT JobList.[Assignment Name], JobList.[Assignment Description], JobList.[Due Date], JobList.[Status],Developers.[Full Name], Developers.[Role]
from JobList
inner join Developers
on JobList.Job_Id = Developers.[Assigned To]
```

Comment: The result you get is how joins work, you cannot have a single row that contains multiple rows.

Comment: Your expected output does not correspond to anything SQL Server would actually output.  Could you live with the full names appearing as CSV, e.g. `User1, User2`?  Or do you want something else?

Comment: You could also pivot the developer names to columns. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server

Comment: What should I do to get a single row ?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].AssignedJobs
AS SELECT JobList.[Assignment Name], JobList.[Assignment Description], 
JobList.[Due Date], JobList.[Status],Developers.[Full Name], Developers.[Role]
from JobList
inner join Developers
on JobList.Job_Id = Developers.[Assigned To]
group by JobList.[Assigment Name], JobList.[Assignment Description], JobList.[Due Date], JobList[Status], string_agg(Developers.[Full Name], ' ') as [Full Name], string_agg (Developers.Role, ' ') as Role
```

If you are not on SQL Server 2017/Azure then use something like this: [Agg with Stuff and XML FOR PATH](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137045/sql-row-concatenation-with-xml-path-and-stuff-giving-aggregate-sql-error)